# Adding An Iframe - Problems

Tags: javascript, java, html, iframe, wordpress

I am trying to grab the Iframe from here:
http://www.neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/HTMLDocs/dvc126/

The code is here:

```
    <iframe width=940 height=700            src="http://www.neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/HTMLDocs/dvc126/" scrolling=no frameborder=0/>
```

but when I add it in the plain text editor on WP it does not work, just a huge white space.

Now I am thinking this is a problem with the Iframe itself? It has no  tag, so maybe  this is why?

Comment: First try to embed simple iframe tag <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe> And also Check whether your browser supports iframe or not

Comment: Hi Java

I have done that to no avail. See here:

    <div>
<iframe src="http://www.neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/HTMLDocs/dvc126/" width="600" height="700" frameborder="0/" scrolling="no"> </iframe>
</div>

 @Java-DK

Comment: I have also done this: 

        <iframe src="http://www.neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/HTMLDocs/dvc126/"></iframe>

Comment: i ended up with a smaller iframe. that is all.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your browser supports iframe or not. [Check](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe)